# App is confusing between application orientation

Tags: flutter, dart

I applied `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);` to my second page of application when I click on button to go new screen where I set portrait orientation my application firstly show in portrait orientation and change its orientation for 1 second to landscape and after 1 second it set back to portrait. I am calling `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);` in `build` function for each class.

Comment: offtopic but force to change device orientation between two different pages is really bad user expirience

Comment: what is the best practice? I need to change the orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change orientation on different screen. where you need to change the orientation just put your screen into rotated box and rotate it to change orientation by `quarterTurns: 2`,. [Rotatedbox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html)